# stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document in Python

Tags: python, selenium, css-selectors, webdriver

I am trying to retrieve all the links to the posts of on instagram account, however it breaks and I am currently struggling to write the proper `WebDriverWait` so I could make it work.

My few attempts have taken me as close as that:

```
    links = WebDriverWait(posts, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".a")))
    links = [elem.get_attribute('href') for elem in links]
```

But it throws  `NameError: name 'By' is not defined`

The code that I am trying to run before any adjustments were made:

```
    browser= webdriver.Chrome('/Users/marialavrovskaa/desktop/chromedriver')
browser.get(f"{instagram_page}")
while scheight < 9.9:
    browser.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight/%s);" % scheight)
    scheight += .01
    posts += browser.find_elements_by_xpath(f"//div[@class='{xpath_to_links}']")
```

## Here the code breaks:

```
links = elem.find_element_by_css_selector('a').get_attribute('href') for elem in posts]
    print(links)
```

I've built my understanding around that error, yet I struggle to make it work with `By.CSS_SELECTOR` settings. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "But it throws NameError: name 'By' is not defined"                      Have you tried: from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

Comment: Yes, still the same.

Comment: Well then what error does it throw? It can't be the same error

Comment: links = [WebDriverWait(elem, 10).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".a"))) for elem in posts] this throws Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
  (Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.149)

Comment: But my question is mainly that I am not sure how should I rewrite and iterate throw posts By CSS_SELECTOR so it will still collect the links